# "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: json, node.js, express

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

I made sure that I was only calling `res.send()` once (or in my case `res.json()`) ([Can't set headers after they are sent node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357634/cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-node-js)) ([NodeJs Can't set headers after they are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734671/nodejs-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)). Then I went on to call return together with my `res.json()` so that nothing can be called after it.

```
app.get('/route/:rID/eta', r_cach.route(1), function(req, res) {
    routes.eta(req.params.rID, req.query.init).then(r => {
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: r});
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: error });
    });
});
```

I'm getting the error on the third bottom line (`return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: error });`). What am I doing wrong?

I don't have any other middleware other than `r_cach` which is the [Express Redis Cache](https://github.com/rv-kip/express-redis-cache). Other than the `r_cach` I add some extra headers using the following code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that `r_cach.route(1)` has something to do with it. What happens when you leave that out?

Comment: @robertklep r_cach is caching with help of https://github.com/rv-kip/express-redis-cache. I'm gonna leave it out for a moment and hope that that's the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code for `r_cach.route(1)`.  The code you show (other than that) does not appear to cause the problem by itself.

Comment: Or, also look to see if you have any other middleware that could be sending a response.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated the question with r_cach and other code. Thank you!

Comment: This error occurs when you have two pieces of code that are both trying to send a response to the same request. It most commonly occurs with errors in async code, but can also occur if middleware is sending a response AND calling `next()` which allows other handlers to see the request and send a response. Given where you are getting the error, it would appear that something before your `app.get()` code you are showing us is sending a response and calling `next()`. Then when your `app.get()` handler tries to send a response, Express says a response has already been sent, can't send another one.

Comment: Also, what does `routes.eta()` do?

Comment: @jfriend00 `routes.eta()` figures out when you are arriving. It's wrapped in a promise handler and returns a `reject()` if anything inside that promise fails, leaving it to the `app.get()` to return that error to the user. The weird part is that I only (but rarely) get this error after a `reject()` has been triggered. If the request is successful I don't see any trace of it.

Comment: None of the code you have shown us would cause that error by itself.  There must be more to it than is shown here.

Comment: @jfriend00 I’m starting to think that maybe ‘r_cach’ might be the reason for the error so I’ll proceed to switch it out of another dependency and see if that might solve it.